# D-H table for youbot

Tags: kinematics, gazebo, collada-urdf, collada, openrave

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to do the forward kinematics for a KUKA youbot and am looking for a table of the D-H parameters (so that I can calculate the rotation matrices). Is there a way in Gazebo that will output the rotation matrices directly?
Can anyone point me to one (a table of a way to output the matrices)?
Thank you!

EDIT:
I'm aware of the tf and KDL libraries... the difference is that I'm trying to OUTPUT the matrices (so that I can study them)
Maybe via the urdf? is that possible?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54678/d-h-table-for-youbot/) by [joe.s](https://answers.ros.org/users/3410/joe.s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 162 on 2013-02-07

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not aware of a way to generate DH parameters directly from URDF.

You can however convert your robot the OpenRAVE format (see for example [here](http://ros.org/wiki/Industrial/Tutorials/Create_a_Fast_IK_Solution) on how to do that). Then, you can generate a table of DH parameters using OpenRAVE's [GetDHParameters](http://openrave.org/docs/latest_stable/openravepy/openravepy_int/#openravepy.openravepy_int.planningutils.GetDHParameters) function.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2013-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joe.s](https://answers.ros.org/users/3410/joe.s/) on 2013-03-06**:
Do you have any examples of how to use OpenRAVE? Specifically that GetDHParameters code?

**Comment by [jesus_hdez_b](https://answers.ros.org/users/25739/jesus_hdez_b/) on 2016-01-26**:
Hi! i finally got the robot.dae and i cannot find an example about how to use the GetDHParameters function in order to get de dh parameters, do you have an example?, or do you have de dh parameters?

**Comment by [sirop](https://answers.ros.org/users/28725/sirop/) on 2017-01-01**:
@jesus_hdez_b
Something like:

```
dh0, dh1, dh2, dh3, dh4 = planningutils.GetDHParameters(myRobot)
```

What makes me wonder is the comment:
*The coordinate systems computed from the DH parameters do not match the OpenRAVE link coordinate systems.*